# JSON from Wikipedia API with GSON - Parse object with varying name

Tags: java, json, gson, wikipedia-api

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "grncontinue": "0.262157292819|0.262157407383|17998004|0",
    "continue": "grncontinue||"
},
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "29839198": {
            "pageid": 29839198,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Paradox (film)",
            "extract": "Paradox is a 2010 science-fiction television film starring Kevin Sorbo, Steph Song and Christopher Judge, directed by Brenton Spencer, and based on a three-part graphic novel mini-series by Christos Gage.\n\n"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a solution for parsing the above JSON result from the Wikipedia API. 
The problem is that since the "29839198" object (in this case) will vary from each API call, I can't seem to find a solution for parsing it.

This is what I have so far:

```
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=random&grnnamespace=0");
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.connect();

JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
JsonElement page = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("?????");
```

Normally I would switch out the "????" part with the object name.

Comment: Isn't pages a Map<Integer, Page> ?

Comment: I would recommend to use the [Jackson library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome/). Yes, you have to write some more classes with annotations, but I it gives you a good abstraction and when you modify your code in a few years, you will still be able to understand your code.

Comment: @beresfordt Is it? Seems like nested JSON objects to me

Comment: @Petter seems like a map for the following reasons: pages.29839198.pageid = 29839198, pages is plural suggesting multiple objects can sit below it, 29839198 is not a meaningful name for an object but is a reasonable key

Comment: @beresfordt
In that case, how can I extract the Map from the `JsonElement`?

Comment: I've not used Gson much, but I expect that you can create a few pojos to represent the api objects, then get gson to deserialise to them. Have a look at Gson databinding. As Schrieveslaach mentions this is also possible in Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use entrySet to get the JsonElement:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=random&grnnamespace=0");
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonElement pages = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("query").getAsJsonObject().get("pages");

        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = pages.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();

        JsonElement yourDesiredElement = null;

        for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
            yourDesiredElement = entry.getValue();
        }

        //null check for yourDesiredElement
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Using entrySet was the solution :)